# Xamarin using Beep()

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, beep

I'm trying to add a beep sound to my Android and IOS project. But eveything I try fails.
I've used [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/System.Console.Beep()/) and a lot other articles but without any success.

If I put in the code: `public static Void Beep ()` I will get the error:

> System.Void cannot be used from C# -- use typeof(void) to get the void type object

And

> Page_BarcodeScanner.Beep() must declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern or partial

I hope anyone can push me in the right direction, since I'm already stuck for 2 days.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-book-samples/tree/master/Chapter09/MonkeyTapWithSound

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Xamarin Forms I think you have to use [DependencyServices](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/) to play a sound.

In Android you can take a look to [Play Audio Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/audio/play_audio/)

in iOS [AvAudioPlayer](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/sound/avaudioplayer/)

I think this prj can be useful as starting point [SimpleAudioForms](https://github.com/tkowalczyk/SimpleAudioForms)